# using homebrew apxs from homebrew apache httpd24 fails with libtool: compile: unable to infer tagged configuration

Tags: apache, homebrew, libtool

using homebrew apxs from homebrew apache httpd24 fails with libtool: compile: unable to infer tagged configuration

```
$ apxs -i -c -Wc,"-arch x86_64" -Wl,"-arch x86_64 " mod_uwsgi.c
/usr/share/apr-1/build-1/libtool --silent --mode=compile cc -prefer-pic   -DDARWIN -DSIGPROCMASK_SETS_THREAD_MASK  -I/usr/local/Cellar/httpd24/2.4.3/include/apache2  -I/usr/include/apr-1   -I/usr/include/apr-1  -arch x86_64  -c -o mod_uwsgi.lo mod_uwsgi.c && touch mod_uwsgi.slo
libtool: compile: unable to infer tagged configuration
libtool: compile: specify a tag with `--tag'
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536
.
```

What environment must I export to have libtool not complain about tag?

Answer (score 4):

after digging through the source I found that if LTFLAGS is set to --tag=cc things work.

```
$ LTFLAGS=--tag=cc apxs -i -c mod_uwsgi.c
```